# Twitter sharing modal dismisses by itself: iOS 10

Tags: ios, twitter, share

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` with built in Twitter sharing feature.

When I press the share twitter button > it opens the modal with a tweet, cancel and post buttons > if I wait for around 10 seconds it dismisses by itself.

Note1: I'm able to post within first 10 seconds. And it successfully posts to my Twitter account.

Note2: When the modal is dismissed the console prints these out:

> 2017-08-07 17:20:26.672518+0300 Aspiration[2150:607322] [core] SLRemoteComposeViewController: (this may be harmless) viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method} 
>   2017-08-07 17:20:26.672600+0300 Aspiration[2150:607322] [core] SLComposeViewController remoteViewController:  didTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method} 
>   2017-08-07 17:20:26.672619+0300 Aspiration[2150:607322] [core] SLComposeViewController completeWithResult: 0 
>   2017-08-07 17:20:26.673083+0300 Aspiration[2150:607322] [core] SLComposeViewController skipping explicit dismiss because isBeingDismissed is already 1 
>   2017-08-07 17:20:26.682171+0300 Aspiration[2150:607322] [core] SLComposeViewController dealloc

Note3: Tested on ios10.3.3 and ios10.2.1. The twitter accounts are set up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appeared to be very specific. But I hope this answer some day will help someone.

The issue was caused by the link that was passed into the tweet. The link contained some referral trackings that didn't allow the internal iOS browser to open the link inside the tweet to show the small "thumbnail".

But: iOS 11 doesn't have this issue (considering that Apple removed built in support of Twitter)

Comment: I believe Apple removed support for all social networks in iOS 11, not just Twitter. Doesn't matter though, implementing your own OAuth solution is fairly trivial.